# How to change the Magento 2.2 Session location from Redis back to File

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.6

I use Magento 2.2.

Changed session destination from file to Redis.

Is there a command to save back to a file?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the configuration either in env.php or cmd

Can change session configuration in **app/etc/env.php**

```
'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'files',
  ),
```

Using Command Line

```
php bin/magento setup:config:set --session-save=files
```

Hope it helps you.